# xpath for a input search box auto suggestion list items as like in google

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate a search box input and selection. First I enter a two character length search string into an input box, when it prompts a list of probable search results, I need to read each item and look for a specific text(partial) and click the one I want. Then the item would be taken as the search string and put into the original input box. Then I press another search box to initiate the search. It is more like our google search.

When I used the Firebug plug in inside the Firefox, I see this code being highlighted. Of course, it is only two items now here but can be a lot more up to 10.

```html
<div class="ac_results" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 400px; top: 135px; left: 520px;">
  <ul>
    <li class="ac_even ac_over">
      EURIBOR 3 MONTH FUT (
      <strong>EB</strong> )
    </li>
    <li class="ac_odd">
      EUR/GBP FUTURES (
      <strong>EB</strong> P)
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I need to be able to iterate the prompted list items, know their text, select the one with matching text, and click on it. Appreciate your help.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Show code you've already tried and describe issues you've faced with your code

Comment: The one I actually happen to use in my code is given below. You may comment on the quality of the solution. "//div[starts-with(@class,'ac_results') and contains(.,'(EB)')]"

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xpath. You will get a list of search results. Create a list of web elements and iterate over an array to verify.

```html
//div[class="ac_results"]//ul//li
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over each one to be able to select the one you want. That's what xpath is for, so you could specify the element you need.
In this case:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ac_results']/ul/li[contains(text(),'" + searchtext + "')]")).click();`

where `searchtext` is either EURIBOR 3 MONTH FUT or EUR/GBP FUTURES

the xpath would be: `//div[@class='ac_results']/ul/li[contains(text(),'EURIBOR 3 MONTH FUT')]`

Comment: Awesome ! Worked like a charm. 
Now I need to understand the logic behind the code snippet.
Learning ! Learning !!

Comment: xpath: looking for any `div` inside the html (double slash means we're not starting from the root) with class `ac_results`..then look for a child `ul` that has a child `li` that has text "EURIBOR 3 MONTH FUT"

Comment: The one I actually happen to use in my code is given below. You may comment on the quality of the solution.
"//div[starts-with(@class,'ac_results') and contains(.,'(EB)')]"

Comment: So you're getting the `div` only? I thought you wanted the items inside the `div`?